# Selenium webdriver I am not able to set Webdriver Firefox i

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set the Webdriver of Firefox. The 'Webdriver' and 'Firefox' got red underlined. I clicked on 'import firefox driver' and 'import webdriver' but the error stays..

What I did:
- I tried to add the Jars again. 
- I downloaded the Gecko driver.
- I clicked on import webdriver and import firefox driver.

But doesn't work at all. I don't really know what to do.

`package testbrowser; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
public class Methods 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox", "C:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); driver.get("google.com/"); 
    } 
}`

Comment: You should post your code here instead of attaching an image

Comment: Ok excuse, package testbrowser;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Methods {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox",
             "C:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
 }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see an error on an import statement, it means that Eclipse cannot find the corresponding library (aka JAR file) on your classpath. Download the selenium standalone server from seleniumhq.org and place it on your classpath. Hint: Right click on your project -> Build Path.

If you haven't already done so, I highly recommend that you spend some time going over the basics of Java and getting familiar with the Eclipse IDE, before you jump into Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Yes, that was the one i was missing!! I had downloaded all the jars and tried it three time but missed this one. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I would appreciate it if you could mark this as the accepted answer, thanks.